# R: Constructing dummy columns based on partial string matches from two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a data frame `df1` with information of acquisitions by ID. Every acquirer `A` and target `B` have their four-digit SIC codes on one line separated by "/".

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
              A = c("1230/1344/2334/2334","3322/3344/3443", "1112/9099", "3332/4483"),
              B = c("1333/2334","3344/8840", "4454", "9988/2221/4483"))

  ID                   A              B
   1 1230/1344/2334/2334      1333/2334
   2      3322/3344/3443      3344/8840
   3           1112/9099           4454
   4           3332/4483 9988/2221/4483
```

I would need to classify each transaction ID as follows:

1. If the primary code (i.e. the first four digits) of either A or B matches any other code than the primary code of B or A, then the Primary.other.match column takes a value of 1 and 0 else.
2. If any other than code the primary code of A or B matches any other than the primary code of B or A, then the Other.other.match column takes value of 1 and 0 else.

The desired output is shown below in the updated df1.

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4),
              A = c("1230/1344/2334/2334","3322/3344/3443", "1112/9099", "3332/4483"),
              B = c("1333/2334","3344/8840", "4454", "9988/2221/4483"),
              Primary.other.match = c(0,1,0,0), #only if primary Code of A or B matches 
any other code of B or A
              Other.other.match = c(1,0,0,1)) # only if primary codes do not match 
primary or any other codes, but any other codes match
ID                   A              B Primary.other.match Other.other.match
 1 1230/1344/2334/2334      1333/2334                   0                 1
 2      3322/3344/3443      3344/8840                   1                 0
 3           1112/9099           4454                   0                 0
 4           3332/4483 9988/2221/4483                   0                 1
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution within the tidyverse.

You first create a function which checks whether there is a primary match or a other match and then apply this function column wise with `purrr::map`:

```
library(tidyverse)

fun1 <- function(str1, str2){
 str1 <- str1 %>% str_split("/") %>% unlist()
 str2 <- str2 %>% str_split("/") %>% unlist()

 str1p <- str1[1]
 str2p <- str2[1]

 pom <- ifelse(str1p %in% str2 | str2p %in% str1, 1, 0)
 oom <- ifelse(pom == 0 & length(intersect(str1, str2)) > 0, 1, 0)

 tibble(pom = pom, oom = oom)

}

df1 %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(result = map2(A, B, fun1)) %>% 
  unnest(result)

# A tibble: 4 x 5
     ID A                   B                pom   oom
  <dbl> <fct>               <fct>          <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 1230/1344/2334/2334 1333/2334          0     1
2     2 3322/3344/3443      3344/8840          1     0
3     3 1112/9099           4454               0     0
4     4 3332/4483           9988/2221/4483     0     1
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I get the error code: "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : could not find function "str_split"". Any ideas?

Comment: check if you have installed the most recent version of the `tidyverse` package.
If you then still have the error try to write `stringr::str_split`.
Otherwise you can use `strsplit(str1, "/")`from base R.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that the tidyverse package was not up to date.